# call a javascript function from java class in vaadin

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to call a javascript function from a java class in a vaadin project. In the past I've used an RPC call to do so, but this time it's only a js function that I need to call, and I thought I would be able to do it with something like `JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("test()");`
So I have a vaadin project and here is the class where I would like to call that function from:

```
package my.vaadin.project.vaadinUploader;



import com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript;
import com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@JavaScript({ "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js", "vaadin://js/script.js" })

public class UploaderComponent extends CustomComponent
{
    final TextField name;
    final TextField surname;
    //final Label div;
    final VerticalLayout formLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    public UploaderComponent(){

        formLayout.addStyleName("myLayout");
        //div = new Label();


        name = new TextField();
        surname = new TextField();
        name.setCaption("Type your name here:");
        surname.setCaption("Type your surname here:");
        formLayout.addComponents(name, surname);

    }


}
```

The script resides in a custom folder but I'm not sure where it is that I can make the call to that js function as I seem to be getting an error all the time. Any idea?

Comment: `as I seem to be getting an error all the time` care to share that error with us?

Comment: sure, apologies I should have done that straightaway. The error isn't in fact in java but I get that in the browser. I added the call in the constructur:
`public UploaderComponent(){
  JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("test()");
  formLayout.addStyleName("myLayout");`
as I had no idea where to add it in to be honest. Anyway I reckon the browser is expecting an RPC call, here is the errors in [chrome console](http://pastebin.com/mFDLhduJ) (I had to use pastebin as it's quite long)

Answer (score 2):

Your call `JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("test()");` is correct, provided the method `test()` is declared properly (which apparently isn't the case).

Assuming the `script.js` source contains the declaration of your `test()` function, likely you've put your `script.js` in the wrong place.

With the `vaadin://` prefix, your file should go relative to the `src/main/webapps/VAADIN` directory, so in your case `src/main/webapps/VAADIN/js/script.js`

If you leave out the `vaadin://` prefix (i.e. `@JavaScript("script.js")`), and you're using Maven, then the proper location of the file is `src/main/resources/` and then the package structure of where your java source was. So in your case `src/main/resources/my/vaadin/project/vaadinUploader/script.js`

Also note that you'll get a warning in the console when accessing an `@Javascript` file that can't be located.

Comment: thanks. Well the path to the folder where I put the js is this: (by the way it's a maven project and not a vaadin one as I've said at the beginning, sorry)
`src/main/webapp/VAADIN/js/script.js` (I've had this structure in another project and it worked). As for the content of the script, here it is:
`function test(){
 console.log("test() inside script.js called");
}`

Comment: in your chrome console, under network tab, do you see this `script.js` file being downloaded correctly?

Comment: thanks. A few things though. I was aware of the 'correct' location but my understanding is that the point of using `vaadin://js/script.js` was to allow you to put your script inside custom folders like `src/main/VAADIN/js` rather than the 'correct' one. I've seen large maaven projects with js files arranged that way, and with only the js connector handling RPC calls in the 'correct' location, that's why I did it that way.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Only my test with `vaadin:` didn't seem to work for some reason. It just dawned on me I forgot the `//`. So testing again with `vaadin://` it works nicely (edited the answer once more). So basically your setup is OK. You should definitely see your `script.js`  being downloaded in chrome network tab - be sure to disable cache though.

Comment: cool glad you got it to work, cos mine still isn't, but it's good to know that my setup is correct and that I'm doing everything the right way, I cleared the cache and tried on two different machines, but still that darn file isn't appearing under source...and I still get that warning in the browser. As a test I replaced the relative URL with the absolute one `http://localhost:8080/vaadinPopup/VAADIN/js/script.js` but I still get the same error in the console...really can't understand why